# Get remote host name using sysctlbyname

Tags: ios, objective-c, hostname

I went through this GitHub [link](https://github.com/dcorbatta/StackoverflowTest/tree/master/InetTest) and was able to get following details.

Socket
Proto 
Recv-Q 
Send-Q
Local Address
Foreign Address
(state)
rxbytes
txbytes
rxbytes[0]
txbytes[0]

How can i get remote hostname through this example?